# Why isn't $0+a=a$ something we derive?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, induction, peano-axioms, natural-numbers

In the usual natural number definition of addition $0+a=a$ is taken as true by definition. This feels like it should be something we derive from $0+0=0$, instead? As in, let's define addition this way:

$0+0=0$

$a+S(b)=S(a+b)$

Then prove the result:

Claim: $0+a=a$

Base case: $0+0=0$ by definition.

Inductive step: Suppose $0+a=a$. We must show that $0+S(a)=S(a)$. By definition of addition, $0+S(a)=S(0+a)$ then by inductive hypothesis equals $S(a)$ and we are done.

In other words we can derive the result rather than assume it true, so why do we skip this step usually?

Comment: It depends on context. In which context did they skip that step?

Comment: If you want to involve the successor function in this, there is no need to derive $a+0=a$, and if you prove commutativity first then you won't have to derive $0+a=a$.

Comment: @KennyLau Any derivation / definition of addition you can find, e.g. Tao's Analysis, ProofWiki, Wikipedia, most textbooks, various sites from Google, etc.

Comment: In fact, now that I think about it, there is no need to derive either $0+a=a$ or $a+0=a$. In the first case you are saying the $a$th successor of $0$ is $a$, which is the definition of $a$, and in the second case you are saying the $0$th successor of $a$ is $a$, which is again true by definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because defined that way you do not know how to compute $a+0$.

The axiom $0+0$ does not apply and neither the axiom $a+S(b)$ does, because $0$ is not a successor.

*Example*: how to compute $1+0$ with the purported definition of sum ? $1$ is $s(0)$: thus, the axiom $0+0=0$ will not work. But $0$ is not $s(n)$ for some $n$: thus, also the axiom $1+s(b)=s(1+b)$ will not work.

---

We must think at the axioms for *sum* (and the same for *product*) as rules to perform sum.

They allows us to complete the task working "backward" step by step.

If we have to compute e.g. $5+3$ we know that $3=s(2)$ and we apply the second axiom to get:

> $5+3=5+s(2)=s(5+2)$.

And then we use the fact that $2=s(1)$ to get:

> $5+3=5+s(2)=s(5+2)=s(5+s(1))=s(s(5+1))$.

Finally, with $1=s(0)$ we get to the end, using the first axiom:

> > $5+3=5+s(2)=s(5+2)=s(5+s(1))=s(s(5+1))=s(s(5+s(0)))=s(s(s(5+0)))=s(s(s(5)))=s(s(6))=s(7)=8.$.

Comment: What do you mean? I know how to prove addition is commutative but that's not what I'm referring to. I'm talking about starting the definition from $0+0=0$ rather than $a$

Comment: Are you saying my inductive proof is wrong somewhere?

Comment: @user525966: No, Mauro is saying that you have proved $0+a=a$, but it may not hold that $a+0=a$. Equivalently, that you may not be able to prove commutativity of addition with only your axioms.

Comment: @user525966 $a+0=a$ *can not* be proven with induction *from* a $+$ operation defined recursively as $0+0=0$ and $S(a+b)=a+S(b)$, *since* $\neg\exists b\in\Bbb N: 0=S(b)$ is axiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

> As in, let's define addition this way:
>   $$0+0=0$$
>   $$a+S(b)=S(a+b)$$

When you attempt to define a function like addition, a good start is to consider it as a general function.  Even granting a domain of natural numbers and that the successor is +1, you have:

$$f(0, 0) = 0$$
$$f(a, b+1) = f(a, b) + 1$$

Try to think of another function with that property.  One that comes to my mind is $f(x, y) = y$.